# Remove redundant lines in short input function

Tags: python, function, dry

I'm trying to sanitize input for a 24-hour clock and the code below is what I came up with. A few lines are repeated and I would like to learn if there's a better pattern to avoid it.

```
def inputHour():
    startHour = input("Starting time (hour): ")
    while not startHour.isdigit():
        startHour = input("Please enter numbers only (0 - 23): ")
    while 0 < int(startHour) > 23:
        startHour = input("Invalid hour. Please enter value from 0 to 23: ")
        while not startHour.isdigit():
            startHour = input("Please enter numbers only (0 - 23): ")
    return startHour
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In total you have 2 options; it is either **not digit** or **not in desired range** as integer. So, maybe you can merge them as below:

```
def inputHour():
    startHour = input("Starting time (hour): ")
    while not startHour.isdigit() or 0 < int(startHour) > 23:
        startHour = input("Invalid input. Please enter numbers only (0 - 23): ")
    return startHour
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I now realize I was tunnel-visioning on the 'proper' error message.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a while loop that only breaks when your input is within the given range:

```
def inputHour():
    while True:
        startHour = input("Starting time (hour, numbers only): ")
        if startHour.isdigit() and (0 <= int(startHour) <= 23):
            break
    return startHour
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will also be adopting your succinct prompt style.